# Adding a number to a range of rows in a data frame (R)

Tags: r, row

I have a set of data (cumulative precipitation) that when the instrument resets, the starting level of the precipitation recorded changes. To correct this, I need to add the amount by which the the value dropped to the new recording so that the values are continuously increasing as they should.

i.e. the range of numbers below would be changed from:
26, 27, 28, 18, 19, 20
to: 
26, 27, 28, 28, 29, 30

By adding the drop (10) to all values after the drop.

I think I need to loop the action through a range of cells (12746 to 17567)

Comment: So it does not reset to 0, like emptying a glass/plastic gauge?  I was expecting +28.

Comment: @David, yeah, I thought that was odd, too. Possibly a mistake in thinking. Then again: We have no idea of neither the setup nor the times and triggers for measurement taking. At icecreamogre: Such details make answering simpler because others can imagine your scenario better and attain a wider range of thinkable solutions.

Comment: Optimally, you would reset the gauge to zero after each reading, or any reading over N, a high point where there is danger of overload/overfill.  Resetting might lose some fractional part.  Having it reset itself means you do not know how much exactly is dumped.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
# An example like yours, but with multiple drops.
vals = c(26, 27, 28, 18, 19, 20, 15, 17, 19);

correct_drops = function(vals)
{
  n = length(vals);

  # which() will get you indices where the condition holds true.
  # Here it will get you the sites where 2 consecutive values
  # have that the first value is greater than the second, meaning a drop.
  indices_before_drop = which(vals[1:(n-1)] - vals[2:n] > 0);

  # Looping through all drops, correcting each individually.
  vals_corrected = vals;
  for (ibd in indices_before_drop)
  {
    iad = ibd + 1;
    drop = vals_corrected[ibd] - vals_corrected[iad];
    vals_corrected = c(vals_corrected[1:ibd], (vals_corrected[iad:n] + drop));
  }

  return (vals_corrected);
}

vals_corrected = correct_drops(vals);
```

Of course there are special cases to be considered.

In any case I believe that `which(..)` and `c(..)` and subvector ranges `v[a:b]` are your friends here.